Wijmo upgrade failing Angular unit tests cannot read properties of undefined
I have recently upgraded grapecity wijmo from v5.20211.794 to v5.20241.9, and since then I have been facing issues with Jasmine unit tests, some tests fail with error “Cannot read properties of “calComponentTable” undefined". BTW, the app is using v15 Angular.
I have tried adding fakeasync, detectchanges() and flush() but nothing is working. With this wijmo latest version which I used i.e., v5.20241.9 has caused other errors too related to tablerow, I have fixed them but not able to fix the above mentioned undefined error.
And this undefined error is related to WjFlexGrid based component internally.
And the line thats causing the error in the spec file is this:
component.wfgComponent.calTableComponent.calComponentTable.fromOnGridInit = false;
And the calTableComponent component class has this line:
@ViewChild(‘calComponentTable’) calTableComponent: CalTableComponent
I have tried adding static true to the above line, but no use.
What code changes I need to do as a solution for this issue?
